# PayPal IPN simulator error - IPN was not sent and the handshake was not verified

Tags: c#, paypal-ipn

I'd like to do some backoffice work whenever a user subscribes to my web app, and after some reading I figured IPN is the way to go.

I'd like to simulate purchase notifications, and debug on my local host. 
For starters - just see the first POST from PayPal (as part of the handshake) -- This is where I fail with the Error.

What I've done so far:

1. Enabled IPN on PayPal and added an IPN handler (ashx) to my project (this is where I expect to see PayPal's POST)
2. I'm using ngrok in order to tunnel my localhost to an external address so PayPal address it.
3. I tried

> openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs

as suggested in other posts and have return code 0.

And I'm still seeing nothing on my server when I hit "Send IPN", and I get the "IPN was not sent" error.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Still the same issue. Anyone?